# Problem installing Dropbox

Tags: 12.04, installation, dropbox

I am having a problem installing Dropbox in Ubuntu 12.04

```
Files in subdirectories of /var are locked preventing the completion of installation
```

Comment: a little details will help us to help you. what you did, what is error.. :)

Comment: How are you installing Dropbox?

Comment: nehoffman I have attempted to install via Software Center and with .deb file with gdebi   ---- in both cases it just hangs  -- an attempt to install in terminal showed errors - locks on files in the sub directories of /var/lib

Answer (score 1):

There could be one of two issues with this.

1. You may not be running the installer as root.
2. You may have another package manager or installer running, or a broken APT.

If you do have a broken APT and you are sure you have exhausted any other option, try removing the lock and doing a reconfigure by doing:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lock
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

This should remove the lock and reconfigure dpkg, so you should be able to install again. be careful not to shut down your PC while installing something via APT again.